# Finding integrating factor for non exact differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve non exact differential equation but I am unable to find the integration factor.

> I solve the following question
> $$-3y\frac{dy}{dx}+2x=0 $$

and I get the integrationg factor $x^{-5/2}$ and I use the proper way to find the integrating factor, but in our text book the integrating facot for above differential equation is finded and that is $y/x^4$.

Now I am completely confused that why please help me out with this.

Comment: Why do you need an integrating factor, you can directly integrate to $-\frac32y^2+x^2=C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-3y\:dy+2x\:dx=0$$
is an EXACT differential equation.

In other words the integrating factor is $1$.
$$d\left(-\frac32 y^2+x^2\right)=0$$
$$-\frac32 y^2+x^2=\text{constant}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$-3y\frac{dy}{dx}+2x=0$$
$$-\dfrac 32 2yy'+2x=0$$
Note that $$((y^2)'=2yy'$$
So that you have:
$$-\dfrac 32 (y^2)'+2x=0$$
Integrate:
$$-\dfrac 32 y^2+x^2=c$$